# When download an image, does urllib have a return code if it's successful or not?

Tags: python, urllib

I want to download an image file from potentially 5 sites.

Meaning that if the image wasn't found in site#1, try site#2, etc.

How can I test if the file was downloaded?

Comment: Why aren't you using `urllib2`?

Answer (score 3):

You can call `getcode()` on the object you get back from `urlopen()`.

`getcode()` gives you the HTTP status response from the server, so you can test to see if you got an HTTP 200 response, which would mean the download was successful.

Comment: Plus, urllib should raise an `IOError` when it can't connect or find your file.

Comment: It's worth checking the `Content-Type` returned as well to see whether it's `image/something` as opposed to `text/html`. Some horribly misguided hosts may respond to a missing file with something stupid and broken like an error page served with `200 OK`, or a `302` redirect. The fatheads.

Comment: I thought the object returned would be the image?

Comment: `urlopen()` returns a file-like object, which behaves mostly like reading any other file, but with some differences, including the `getcode()` function. See http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen